# jquery dialog not showing scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have this definition for the jquery dialog plugin:

```
$("#DonateForm").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    minWidth: 600,
    maxWidth: 700,
    minHeight: 250,
    maxHeight: 350,
    resizable: true
});
```

I have a complicated DIV form like:

```
<div id="DonateForm">
  <div id="DonateFormInner">
    .. Complex form ..
  </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason, the plugin doesn't scroll... any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minXXX, maxXXX settings define the minimum and maximum width and height values that the dialog can be *resized* to. You can define a starting width and height when creating the dialog and the scroll bar will appear when the dialog is initially rendered.

Comment: Thanks, that's what was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to give your container "overflow: auto":

```
<div id='DonateForm' style='overflow: auto'>
</div>
```

Depending on the situation, it might be easier to work with the inner `<div>`.

Comment: by "work with the inner div", do you mean apply the plugin to the inner DIV, or apply the styles to the inner DIV?

Comment: No, I meant to get the style/look that you want. It depends on what the rest of the dialog looks like, etc.